# Adding socket to redux results in serialization warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, socket.io

This is my code:

```
export const Wrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const authState = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const { clientsState, setClientsState } = useContext(ClientsContext);

  const token = getAuthenticationToken();

  // Configure socket
  useEffect(() => {
    if (authState.socket) return;
    const socket: SocketIOClient.Socket = WebsocketClient.connect('...', token);
    dispatch(setAuthState({ ...authState, socket, isAuthenticated: true }));
  });
});
```

authSlice.ts

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { IAuthState } from '../../types';

const initialState: IAuthState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  profile: null,
  socket: null,
};

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setAuthState(state, action: PayloadAction<IAuthState>) {
      state = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setAuthState } = authSlice.actions;
export const authReducer = authSlice.reducer;
```

I am trying to pass socket, to redux, since I need to call various methods on it later. But when doing this I get this error:

```
A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `payload.socket`. Value: 
Object { io: {…}, nsp: "/", json: {…}, ids: 0, acks: {}, receiveBuffer: [], sendBuffer: [], connected: false, disconnected: true, flags: {}, … }
 
Take a look at the logic that dispatched this action:  
Object { type: "auth/setAuthState", payload: {…} }
 
(See https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#why-should-type-be-a-string…t-least-serializable-why-should-my-action-types-be-constants) 
(To allow non-serializable values see: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#working-with-non-serializable-data)
```

Which I understand. It leads me [here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#working-with-non-serializable-data), and the explanation makes sense. I need to add an exception in the store config.

My question is how do I do it? Where do I get this data?

```
configureStore({
  //...
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware({
    serializableCheck: {
      // Ignore these action types
      ignoredActions: ['your/action/type'],
      // Ignore these field paths in all actions
      ignoredActionPaths: ['meta.arg', 'payload.timestamp'],
      // Ignore these paths in the state
      ignoredPaths: ['items.dates'],
    },
  }),
}) // from docs
```

Comment: Would it not be a better idea to keep the socket in your thunk? Redux state is not meant to store such objects and you won't know what extensions will break later by forcing this in there.

Comment: I'll give it a read